# Why can't I write on the virtual device?

Tags: c

Why does the virtual device doesn't present the sprintf? It does open the window and sets the background color, but doesn't present anything else in the window (like the sprintf and g2_string commands).

```
char str[256];

case'2':

    dev=g2_open_X11(750, 500); 
    d=g2_open_vd();
    g2_clear(d);
    g2_set_font_size(d, 14); 
    g2_attach(d, dev); 

    g2_set_auto_flush(d, 0);
    g2_pen(d, 0);
    g2_set_background(d, 1);

    sprintf(str, "Atitude:   %.4f graus", alfa);
    g2_string(d, 30, 250, str);

    sprintf(str, "Altitude:   %.4f m", ht);
    g2_string(d, 30, 230, str);

    sprintf(str, "Distancia horizontal:   %.4f m", xt);
    g2_string(d, 30, 210, str);

    sprintf(str, "Velocidade em x:   %.4f m/s", vxt);
    g2_string(d, 30, 190, str);

    sprintf(str, "Velocidade em z:   %.4f m/s", vzt);
    g2_string(d, 30, 170, str);

    sprintf(str, "Combustivel:   %.4f Kg", m_comb);
    g2_string(d, 30, 150, str);
break;
```

Comment: What is `str` and how is it declared?

Comment: It's declared like this: char str[256];

Comment: You should edit your question to improve it. Your code is not purely standard C99 ("virtual devices" are not in standard C99). It uses some library (which one?) and is perhaps operating system specific (which OS, compiler, compilation command do you use?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming [this](http://www.ib.cnea.gov.ar/~oop/g2/group__interface.html) is the library you're using, you need to either enable auto-flush (you've disabled it with the `g2_set_auto_flush(d, 0);` call) or call [`g2_flush`](http://www.ib.cnea.gov.ar/~oop/g2/group__control.html#gc7db6077da6b358b4b67f08f4b5b093e) whenever you've completed a batch of operations that you want to appear.

Comment: It's still not working...

    case '2':

     dev=g2_open_X11(750, 500); 
     d=g2_open_vd();
     g2_clear(d);
     g2_set_font_size(d, 14); 
     g2_attach(d, dev); 
  
     g2_pen(d, 0);
     g2_set_background(d, 1);

     sprintf(str, "Atitude:   %.4f graus", alfa);
     g2_string(d, 30, 250, str);

     g2_flush(d);